# after migrate sql runs after reboot of the application with no migration performed

Tags: flyway

I'm using Flyway 6.5.7 and I have a afterMigrate.sql that truncates a table. I thought the script would run only if a migration occurred AND if the migration is successful. But it always runs (for example after restart of the application)

```
Schema "A_SCHEMA" is up to date. No migration necessary.
Parsing afterMigrate.sql ...
Executing SQL callback: afterMigrate -
```

Is it correct? If so, is there a way to achieve the described behavior?

Note: org.flywaydb.core.Flyway#migrate returns 0 after restart of the application with no migration

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is the afterMigrate callback runs after any migration that didn't have an error. A successful migration is defined that way. So, in your situation, you called the migrate command. It ran successfully. It didn't migrate anything. However, it ran without an error, so the afterMigrate callback ran.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `afterEachMigrate` event which you can attach a callback to. This runs after each successful execution of a migration script; it doesn't run if `migrate` finds nothing to do, but on the downside it will run more than once if `migrate` finds multiple scripts that it needs to run. Depending on how often you push out new scripts, this might be a better solution for you.